# How can I map links from a TFS 2010 work item to another work item using TFS Integration Tools?

Tags: mapping, tfs-workitem, tfsintegrationplatform

Unfortunately we've got the problem that we have to "migrate" work items of type "User Story" to another customised work item type in the same Team Project on our TFS 2010 installation.

I managed to get most of the field mapping working using the TFS Integration tool and the [IntegrationPlatformMappingTool](http://tfsintegrationmapper.codeplex.com/releases/view/59309) (can be found on Codeplex). I do, however, not know how I can migrate the information about linked work items to the new work item type. In the work item type definition for the User Story I usually have a "Field Name" for each control in the associated form, e.g. System.AreaPath or something similar. For the links I don't have that information, the Work Item Type designer only shows a control of type "LinkControl" with an empty field name.

Is there a way to also migrate existing links when using the TFS Integration tool? How would I do this in the mapping file?

Thank you,

G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't say it's an "acceptable answer" but Links are not field in Work Item, that's why you can't find a mapping for them.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/10/20/tfs-integration-tools-can-i-migrate-all-work-items-from-one-team-project-collection-to-another.aspx) tends to confirm that you won't have links between work item migrated, but only link between changeset and work item.

I can't help you further but it's a start (and better than nothing! :))

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no easy way around it. I thought about writing a bit of code that would process linked items while migrating the work items, so maybe this will work then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the TFS Integration Platform (http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), there is a specific section for migrating links over. Here would be an example

```
<Linking>
  <LinkTypeMappings>
    <LinkTypeMapping LeftMigrationSourceUniqueId="{GUID for Left Migration Source}" LeftLinkType="System.LinkTypes.Dependency" RightLinkType="System.LinkTypes.Dependency" RightMigrationSourceUniqueId="{GUID for Right Migration Source" />
  </LinkTypeMappings>
</Linking>
```

These definitions are not part of the field mapping section of the configuration XML, but exist at the same level as the `Sessions` element.

Comment: @gorgsenegger: Did you try this?

Comment: How do I find the GUIDs?

Comment: @Kangkan I have used this successfully in the past (not only from TFS to TFS but it also works for ClearQuest to TFS). The GUIDs for the migration sources should be located in the configuration XML where the sources are defined.

Comment: May I get some elaborated step to do it? I am also doing something similar and not getting the links in TFS. I added CR and DT in CQ with link from CR to DT and wanted them to be migrated. The CR and DT gets migrated, but the links are missing.